# SQL Server : most frequent value in each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

How can I find most frequent value in each row in SQL Server?

Example:

```
1 a d a a c a b  -->    a
2 b a c b b b d  -->    b
3 h a h h b c d  -->    h    
4 d d c h g p m  -->    d
5 e e g h d e h  -->    e
```

In first row, 'a' is most frequent value, etc.

Comment: Are the values in different columns?

Comment: Please add the actual table structure with some example data.

Comment: Is it a single varchar column with values like `'a d a a c a b'`? If you have multiple columns you should consider to refatcor it. Create another table which is linked via foreign-key and contains one record per column. This proces is called database normalization and is important to simplify such tasks or make queries like this more efficient.

Comment: select right(left('1 a d a a c a b',3),1)

Comment: @jarlh yes in the above example, I have 7 column and 5 row. (row number is just for refrence and is not value)

Comment: @tim-schmelter no, values is in different columns (7 columns) . values may have more characters like : jack,tom,jim,tom,tom,jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering these values are in separate columns, with an `UNPIVOT` query the solution would look something like.....

**Test Data**

```
Declare @T table (ID INT , Col1 varchar(1) , Col2 varchar(1) , Col3 varchar(1)
             , Col4 varchar(1) , Col5 varchar(1) , Col6 varchar(1) , Col7 varchar(1))
Insert Into @T values
('1','a','d','a','a','c','a','b'),
('2','b','a','c','b','b','b','d'),
('3','h','a','h','h','b','c','d'),
('4','d','d','c','h','g','p','m'),
('5','e','e','g','h','d','e','h');
```

**Query**

```
WITH X AS (
Select ID , Val,  COUNT(*)total
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
from @T 
 UNPIVOT (Val FOR N IN (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7))up
GROUP BY ID , Val 
)
Select t.* ,  Val 
FROM X 
INNER JOIN @T t ON x.ID = t.ID 
WHERE rn = 1
```

**Result Set**

```
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 | Val |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
|  1 | a    | d    | a    | a    | c    | a    | b    | a   |
|  2 | b    | a    | c    | b    | b    | b    | d    | b   |
|  3 | h    | a    | h    | h    | b    | c    | d    | h   |
|  4 | d    | d    | c    | h    | g    | p    | m    | d   |
|  5 | e    | e    | g    | h    | d    | e    | h    | e   |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+
```

Comment: Well done for seeing that this was multiple columns and not one string +1